# Looking for a video game movie possibly made in the 80's

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

Can't really come up with more of a vague title than that I guess, but honestly that's the best I can describe the movie I'm looking for.

From what I can remember these two young boys meet up and are playing video games. One of them is overly good at playing video game, freakishly good. The other boy has an older sister who he calls 'hooker' when they get into a sibling spat while the two boys are playing video games. The brother and sister both are amazed at the other boys 'talent' to play video games.

Now that's about all I can remember about the movie. I have a feeling that the 'talented' video game player isn't really 'talented' but that there is something else there. I can't remember most of the movie but that scene has played in my head over and over a thousand times for years now and I've still not figured out what movie that is. Any help is appreciated.

I'm fairly certain that the movie I'm looking for isn't The Wizard (1989), WarGames (1983), or Cloak & Dagger (1984). But they do come close to what I'm looking for and have a similar look and feel with a video game centralized theme. It's also not likely The Last Starfighter (1984). I don't remember there being any thing about space or going into outer space in the movie. Aside from that the two boys are much younger.

Comment: Maybe [The Last Starfighter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Starfighter) ?

Comment: No that doesn't look to be the right one either. I had seen that come up in my search as well but threw it out of contention because of the outer space theme. The two boys are younger, much younger.

Comment: How old do you think they are? You never say.

Comment: The two boys seem to be about 10-12 year's old, but I could be wrong.

Comment: There is a movie from 1983 called "Nightmares"  It's comprised of different short stories.  The one story has Emilio Estevez as a video game wizard, not sure if this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like it could be the movie [D.A.R.Y.L.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D.A.R.Y.L.) from 1985. In the movie, Daryl turns out to be an android which has the uncanny ability to play video games. The government lost him, was found by an elderly couple, and later was introduced to a brother/sister living either nearby or next door. Daryl has amnesia and cannot remember that he's an android. The government finds out where he is and takes him back.

It's been a long time since I've seen the movie, but it seems about right by your description.

Comment: Indeed, and the brother also calls his sister 'hookie'.

Comment: I didn't even think about that one! <palm to forehead>

Comment: That's it! Found a clip of the scene that I remembered seeing on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3whW65Xl54) And @Walt you're correct he does call is sister 'hookie'. I heard it as 'hooker' years ago when I first saw it. Thank you all so much!